# Getting GeoPoint data from Cloud Boost database

Tags: database, cloud

How do I get GeoPoint data from Cloud Boost database? The doc are not clear how to do this and they actually don't even show how to do it.

Comment: "and they actually do even show how to do it" They do? Well then...

Comment: My mistake. That was a typo. I can not figure out how to accomplish this.